# SSIS appverifUI.dll getting picked up in Foreach Loop task

Tags: ssis

[image]I'm trying to run a foreach container task and running into an issue where this file is being picked up as the filename when I go to archive the file I just processed. The weird thing is the previous dataflow task with the file I actually want to move works fine, but for some reason when I go to move the file to an archive location the variable changes to this dll file.

I tried specifying the .xlsx file extension in the foreach container but then none of the files were found.

Comment: How do you have the foreach configured? What files are in the folder (and potentially subfolders) that the foreach is pointing. Screenshot is helpful when creating questions on SSIS due to the UIs ability to strew values hither and yon

Comment: Attached the picture. I'm actually thinking I misread the error and it's unable to find the appverifUI.dll and not able to move to the second step which is to archive the file after it's loaded.

Comment: How do you have the foreach enumerator configured?

Comment: @billinkc Thank you! You got me on the right track. The issue was with the enumerator configuration. It was still set to C:\.